# Default Java Trust Store (cacerts) with TLS connection over HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: java, ssl

I am new newbie in TLS , HTTPS handshaking.
I read a  lot of articles ,question ,work around and still have some basic doubts.

My understanding is like below :

1. Every JRE comes with a default truststore known as cacerts with password as changeit.
2. This cacerts stores well known certificates.
3. If I am writing a client code to invoke Rest, I will be given a certificate which I need to import into default trust store (cacerts) along with root or intermediate certificates.
4. Once I do that , I don't have to write any specific code to invoke Rest API or for that matter any URL.

I should be okay with just

```
URL url = new URL("https://10.10.10.10:1000/*****");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I basically want to confirm that I don't need to create SSLContect , Trustmanager or set System properties to let JVM know what is trust store , keystore, password to both . because everything is already present in default cacerts , I should be good.

If all above is correct:
Why on client I will ever create a new (custom) trust store, why not import everything in default cacert trust store ?

With all above in mind  , I am getting error :
No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.10.10.10 found,

which I believe is because in the certificate I have, there is no mapping, which is as below :

```
: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false

SubjectAlternativeName [
 DNSName: esbtest.test.gov
]
```

so to resolve this, I need to get the certificate updated in server to include IP mapping in SAN.

Comment: Hey , that was just a mock url , though I updated.